# Combining keyup(Enter) and blur events together

Tags: jquery, blur, keyup

I've tried some similar solutions, but those were just similar.

I'd like to execute some functions on either `Enter` key press or `Blur`. In this case they're supposed to do the same.

```
$(".some_input").on("keyup blur", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    // some function to be executed on both of the events
  }
})
```

So I need to add something like:

```
if(e.keyCode === 13 || blur) {
```

That's all I need and can't achieve by myself indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your shared function

```
function myFunction() { }
```

Then create 2 different handlers, and call the function:

```
$(".some_input").on("blur", myFunction).on("keyup", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        myFunction();
    }
});
```